# Is it possible to use D2XX to interface with a non-FTDI device?

Tags: windows, serial-port, ftdi, d2xx

This is on Windows 10.

In my project we previously used D2XX to interface with a FTDI USB-to-Serial device. It worked great.

Now we introduced an additional USB-to-Serial device, but I've just realized that it wasn't actually a FTDI device. It appears as a generic Microsoft "USB Serial Device":

[image]

So of course the FTD2XX library does not recognize it and it does not come out when we enumerate connected devices through *FT_GetDeviceInfoList*.

> The D2XX interface is a proprietary interface specifically for FTDI devices.

**I am aware that the straightforward fix is to not use D2XX for this device, but rather the [generic Windows Fileapi interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/).**

However, to reduce code duplication, I am wondering if there is a way to "wrap" the generic driver so that we can interface to it using the FTD2XX library?

Comment: Nope, no driver except the FTDI one supports the IOCTL calls that the FTD2XX library does.

Comment: They will depend on the D2XX functions you are using. It depends on whether they can be implemented by the Win32API at a reasonable cost. The easiest is if you are only using the D2XX Win32API compatibility feature (FT\_W32\_Xxxx). In that case, in addition to the general file API, these APIs that specialize in serial port processing are available. [Communications Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/communications-functions)

Comment: do you use only the VCP functionaliy of the ft devices? If so you could use the generic windows functions instead (CreateFile, GetCommState, etc.).

Comment: No, we use functions like FT_GetDeviceInfoList.